# Doesn't see any data in my post

Tags: php, mysql

I don't see any data in my index.php page. I use this code to get the data from mysql database with unique id, but i can't.

```
include "db/db.php";    
$upload_path = "secure/content/blogpostimg";

<?php
if (isset($_GET['post_id']) && $_GET['post_id'] != '')
{
$p_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];
}   
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE post_id = '$pid' ORDER BY post_id 
DESC ");

while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$id = $rel['post_id'];
$sub = $rel['subject'];
$imgname = $rel['img_name'];
$msg = $rel['message'];
$date = $rel['date'];
$poster = $rel['poster'];
$cat_name = $rel['cat_name'];

echo "<h1>". "$sub" ."</h1>". "<br/>";
echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . '/' . $imgname . '" width="200"  />  ';       
include_once("func.php");
echo truncate($rel['message'],"index.php","post_id",$rel['post_id']);      
echo "$date&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "<b>Category:</b>    
&nbsp;$cat_name". "&nbsp;&nbsp;".  "<b>by:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "$poster&nbsp;&nbsp;" . 
"<b>Comemnts</b>[&nbsp;  ]" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: The code you have posted is invalid. Please try to post working code.

Comment: Here is my index.php code. http://www.dawamedical.com/index.txt

Comment: it seems too much typing mistakes in this code

Comment: are you new in typing too? only you need is just carefully paste the actual code you are using.

Comment: Are you sure is database connection OK?

Answer (score 3):

The first two lines of code are before the open tag:
    <?php

Comment: Are your script working?

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

add these 2 lines at the very top of your code and read an answer to your question
this will let you spot those silly typos you are started with.

now, let's do the same thing to SQL

make your code like this

```
if (isset($_GET['post_id']))
{
  $p_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];
}
else
{
  die('Required variable is not set');
}  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE post_id = $p_id";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
if (!mysql_num_rows($res))
{
  die("No records found");
}
```

Comment: it's show Undefined variable: p_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\index2.php on line 102

Comment: well, you are using such an undefined variable somewhere. check your code regarding this variable

Comment: Sure, go check your actual code. do you at least call your index.php with post_id in the address bar?

Comment: this is the code of my index.php, Pls see this..http://www.dawamedical.com/index.txt

Comment: Same error show pls check my index.php code

Comment: **do you call your index.php with post_id in the address bar?**

Comment: yes, but still get error message

Comment: what line this error points to?

Comment: i use...http://localhost/evantechbd/index2.php?post_id=42 and get Notice: Undefined variable: p_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\index2.php on line 102

Comment: why did you comment out $_GET and start using $_POST?

Comment: sorry It's maybe my mistake, what's the right? I'm new in php/mysql

Comment: Well it's doesn't show any error message but show a Blank page

Comment: go check, if you have such record in database. echo $sql; echo mysql_num_rows($sql);

Comment: Yes, there are 2 records

Comment: I see it with phpmyadmin

Comment: don't tell me about 2 records. I am talking of this very record you are requesting in this code. ok, see an addition to my answer

Comment: now try to alter your code as shown above and see what does it say

Comment: Sorry to Delay my Answer. It's "Required variable is not set", So how do i fix this?

Comment: you are NOT calling your script this way then: http://localhost/evantechbd/index2.php?post_id=42

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable **$p_id**

But in query you use **$pid** variable name.

Comment: Oh i changed this but still get nothing